# How can I check if jquery is loaded from external JS file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an external JS file to manage all script in my page.
I want to write in this file some code to check if jquery plugin is loaded and (if not) load it!

I tried to begin my myScripts.js file with this code:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

And in my index.html

I did this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

    <head>
        <script src="myScripts.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <button id="test">test</button>

        <script>

        $('#test').click( function() {

            alert('clicked');

        });

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

But it's not performing the alert dialog.. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the jquery file using the script.it would not available so you have to add onload listener to detect the when it's available.

```
function fnjquery() {
    $('#test').click( function() {

        alert('clicked');

    });
}

if(typeof jQuery=='undefined') {
    var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var jqTag = document.createElement('script');
    jqTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    jqTag.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js';
    jqTag.onload = fnjquery;
    headTag.appendChild(jqTag);
} else {
     fnjquery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose `click` event in `$(document).ready` to ensure that the event gets fired when `DOM` is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#test').click( function() {

            alert('clicked');

        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrx3qvbh/)

```js
function myJQueryCode() {
    //Do stuff with jQuery
    $('#test').click( function() {
            alert('clicked');
        });
}

if(typeof jQuery=='undefined') {
    var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var jqTag = document.createElement('script');
    jqTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    jqTag.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js';
    jqTag.onload = myJQueryCode;
    headTag.appendChild(jqTag);
} else {
     myJQueryCode();
}
```

```html
<button id="test">
click
</button>
```